# .NET Core authentication cookie: can I set a custom auto-renewal threshold?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5, asp.net-authentication

I'm developing a `.NET 5` Web Application, and I'm using the ASP.NET Cookie mechanism for authentication.
In my `ConfigureServices` method, I have:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie(op => {
        op.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });
```

This means, as the `SlidingExpiration` property's documentation explains, that:

> the handler will re-issue a new cookie with a new expiration time any
> time it processes a request which is more than halfway through the
> expiration window.

This works correctly, however I wanted to know if there is a way to change the renewal threshold? By default the cookie is renewed if a request arrives to the server that is "more than halfway through the expiration window". My question is: can I set it, for example, to renew if the cookie is older thank X minutes? Or to renew at every request?

Comment: You can set custom expireation time by setting this property `ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20)` . You can have a look [here in official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0#absolute-cookie-expiration)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron: I think you misunderstand the question, I'm not asking how to set the cookie expiration time, I'm asking how to configure the age threshold at which the cookie is auto-renewed

Comment: Okay thanks to point that out.